# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_17_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict

I have trained a model for Handwritten digit recognition from MNIST. 
The input shape of 1st Conv2D is (28, 28, 1)
After training, I wanted to predict a downloaded image of a digit.
The shape of the image was (1024, 791, 3), upon applying the following code i resized the image to (28,28,1) and called model.predict() :

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
#resized_image = tf.image.resize(image, size = (28,28))
resized_image = resized_image / 225.0
resized_image = resized_image[:,:,:1] 
prediction = model.predict(resized_image)
#prediction = model.predict(resized_image, batch_size = 1, verbose = 1, steps = 1)
print(labels[np.argmax(prediction)])
```

But i am getting following error:

> Error when checking input: expected conv2d_17_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)

model is :

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'Same', activation = 'relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'Same', activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax")
])
```

I have also tried uncommenting

```
resized_image = tf.image.resize(image, size = (28,28))
prediction = model.predict(resized_image, batch_size = 1, verbose = 1, steps = 1)
```

Yet i received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show your model, but usually, you need to consider the batch. So, your input must be `[batch_size, width, height, channel]`. If you have just one image, you must set `batch_size=1`, in your case, `[1, 28, 28, 1]`.

Also, make sure your input is a `tf.tensor`.

Comment: As you have said, i have updated the model in the question and also tried uncommenting those two lines(resizing image by using tf and keeping batch_size=1 in model.predict) . And by "make sure your input is a tf.tensor" did u mean that i have change the downloaded image into tensor using tf.io.decode_image?

Comment: I think you should have a look at the [load images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) tutorial that TF provides on its website. The function `def decode_img(img)` does what I'm saying, but it doesn't consider a batch, you need to include it.